# Mongodb collection update patterns

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in db(e.g. merchants) which gets updated regularly in prod.
What we have is a db population script that we run every time.

This removes configuration collections and inserts them again based on data in script e.g. includes the update to a merchant config.

```
db.merchants.remove({});
db.merchants.insert(themerchant);
```

Is there a better pattern/procedure that people use to do this?
I cant seem to find guidance on how people are doing this in production. Links to methods people use would be great.

E.g. In SQL Server we create patches

Comment: Why don't you update the changes rather than completely removing the document and then reinserting it?